# Javascript month is wrong

Tags: javascript, date

Please someone tell me why the month gets increased by 1 if its value is higher than 9. The code is below

```
var dd = new Date();
dd.setFullYear(2017);
dd.setMonth(7);
console.log("Month(Expecting 7, and received 7) = " + dd.getMonth());
dd.setMonth(10);
console.log("Month(Expecting 10, and received 11) = " + dd.getMonth());
```

Fiddler code at here - https://jsfiddle.net/vzmtp3ua/

Comment: It's because this month has 31 days, so the day is currently 31.  There's no 31st of November ;)

Answer (score 4):

Because 31 days do not exist in every month so the extra days are added to the next month.

Set Date as Oct 31, add a month so it would be November 31st since there are 30 days the date is moved to December 1st.

Answer (score 2):

In some months there are less days then 31 , So extra days are added to the following month

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the number of days in that month making the date shift to the first day in the next month. 
The documentation mentions this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth

> The current day of month will have an impact on the behaviour of this method. Conceptually it will add the number of days given by the current day of the month to the 1st day of the new month specified as the parameter, to return the new date. For example, if the current value is 31st August 2016, calling setMonth with a value of 1 will return 2nd March 2016. This is because in 2016 February had 29 days.

Answer (score 1):

Not all the months have same number of days (31) so next one will be moved to next month

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Date object on 31th of October and then set the month to November (= 10!), which does not have 31 days, it will switch to the 1st of next month (December 1st).

Answer (score 0):

It's dependent on current date. You initialize the date to "now" (`new Date()`), and today is Oct 31st.

If the day on your Date object is 31st and you call `setMonth()`, extra days will get carried on to the next month for months shorter than 31 days. If you try to `setMonth(1)` it will mean Feb 31st, so you get Mar 3rd.

To avoid the problem you can pass second argument the `setMonth`, which is the day to be set, e.g. `dd.setMonth(10,30)` (Nov 30).